# Does my electric panel need replacing?

Tags: electrical, breaker-box, troubleshooting

How can I tell if my electric panel needs replacing? Got up today and suddenly I lost power to a tandem breaker the breakers weren't tripped. Then realized I also lost my water pump. The water pressure switch needs to be replaced. Also have little to no power on another breaker on the same side of the box. The other breakers on that side seem to be working ok. The tandem breaker was changed, still no power. Seems like the connector to the breaker has no power even though the back of the panel has power. Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check out a few additional things. From the information you've provided, your panel and breakers could be fine, but the wiring between panel and fixtures could be damaged. You can use a non-contact electrical tester to check the wiring at a few points. Start with the cables exiting your panel, and see if you can follow along to the fixtures that aren't working. If the tester indicates no power immediately outside the panel, then the problem is inside your panel. Otherwise, a little detective work can help you identify where the wiring problems may be.